# Why won't the tab be inserted on the first added line?

Tags: sed, gnu-sed

I am trying to add multiple lines to a file, all with a leading a tab. The lines should be inserted on the first line after matching a string.

Assume a file with only one line, called "my-file.txt" as follows:

```
foo
```

I have tried the following sed command:

```
sed "/^foo\$/a \tinsert1\n\tinsert2" my-file.txt
```

This produces the  following output:

```
foo
tinsert1
    insert2
```

Notice how the the tab that should be on the first (inserted) line is omitted. Instead it prints an extra leading 't'.

Why? And how can I change my command to print the tab on the first line, as expected?

Comment: I'm also using gnu sed 4.7 (on manjaro-linux)

Comment: Specifically 4.7-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^foo$/a \\tinsert1\n\tinsert2' file
     <---- single quotes!      --->
```

Produces:

```
foo
    insert1
    insert2
```

From the manual:

> ```
>   a \
>
>   text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
> ```

Since the text to be append itself has to to be preceded by a backslash, it needs to be `\\t` at the beginning.

---

PS: If you need to use double quotes around the sed command because you want to inject shell variables, you need to escape the \ which precedes the text to be appended:

```
ins1="foo"
ins2="bar"
sed "/^foo\$/a \\\t${ins1}\n\t${ins2}" file
```

Comment: Yes, that is why I needed the double quotes. I had tried \\t but did'nt think of \\\t :)

Comment: @unique_ptr since GNU(!) sed interprets the `\t` and `\n` itself, the following would also work: `sed "/^foo\$/a \\\\t${ins1}\\n\\t${ins2}" file`  :)

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings, that is all. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{print} $0=="foo"{print "\tinsert1\n\tinsert2"}' file
foo
        insert1
        insert2
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and is trivial to modify to do anything else you might want to do in future.